# Can place a TextView inside a ImageView?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm programming a spinning roulette  that contains punishments, I have a ImageView control that's is able to rotate(inside the ImageView I have the image of the spinning wheel). Now I want to let the user to create custom punishments. In the view before the spinning roulette the user is able to enter his own punishments & it pass the string values to a TextView. Now what I'm trying to figurated if is possible to place those text views inside the ImageView so the new punishments rotate whit in the spinning roulette.

Here is the code full code:

```
public class ruleta4F extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView imageRoulette;
    private  FrameLayout mainView;

    TextView ruletaNombre;
    TextView castigo1,castigo2,castigo3,castigo4;


    TextView nombreRuleta4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ruleta4_f);
        imageRoulette = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_roulette);




        mainView = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainView);


        /////////////////get data
        ruletaNombre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView12);
        String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("namer");
        ruletaNombre.setText(name);



        castigo1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        String sc1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("sc1");
        castigo1.setText(sc1);

        castigo2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
        String sc2= getIntent().getStringExtra("sc2");
        castigo2.setText(sc2);


        castigo3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);
        String sc3= getIntent().getStringExtra("sc3");
        castigo3.setText(sc3);


        castigo4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView11);
        String sc4= getIntent().getStringExtra("sc4");
        castigo4.setText(sc4);




    }



    public void actionRoulette(View view) {



        int corner = 360/38; // corner for point
        int randPosition = corner * new Random().nextInt(38); // random point
        int MIN = 5; // min rotation
        int MAX = 9; // max rotation
        long TIME_IN_WHEEL = 1000;  // time in one rotation
        int randRotation = MIN + new Random().nextInt(MAX-MIN); // random rotation
        int truePosition =  randRotation * 360 + randPosition;
        long totalTime = TIME_IN_WHEEL * randRotation + (TIME_IN_WHEEL/360) * randPosition;

        Log.d("ROULETTE_ACTION","randPosition : " + randPosition
                + " randRotation : " + randRotation
                + " totalTime : " + totalTime
                + " truePosition : " + truePosition);

        ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view,"rotation",0f,(float)truePosition);
        animator.setDuration(totalTime);
        animator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
                mainView.setEnabled(false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                mainView.setEnabled(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

            }
        });
        animator.start();

    }

}
```

Comment: Place the TextView and ImageView inside a container layout , and rotate that container layout?

Comment: If you are interested in drawing text inside image then have a look at https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable But I am sure this is not the best solution for your problem

Comment: i can't find the container layout, what is the exact name?

Comment: Okay i put inside the container layout the TextView and ImageView, and i change the code but the text still not moving only the image i will update the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Frame Layout. In this case you can put your views where you want

Comment: can give me a short close up?

Comment: Hey i got ImageView and TextView inside a Frame Layout but still can't figurate out in the code how to rotate the frame layout can you help me on this?